# How to Get Dynamic Map Service Layer Name On ArcGIS API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/sp920ee7/1/) and let me know how I can get the Selected Layer Name through API when check boxes are checked?

As you can see at [This Link](https://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/ESRI_StatesCitiesRivers_USA/MapServer) the service is providing 3 layers as:

[image]

and I need to get these names as they are selected
I already tried the [Request layer info](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/data_requestLayerInfo.html) but this seems retuns metadata about fields only.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned , you have to set an ajax request to `service-url?f=json`
and loop the Layers tab json response to access each layer name , id ...

same thing to generate check boxes .

required js =>

> `"esri/request",` ajax req
>
> `"dojo/dom-construct",`  creating dynamic checkbox
>
> `"dojo/_base/array",`  looping json Layers array

You can find a sample solution here : => [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sp920ee7/12/)

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for metadata describing the layer names, the request you need to make is to the map service itself

https://sampleserver5.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Energy/Geology/MapServer/?f=json

each id and name can be found inside the `layers` array within the json response.